# github http clone returns 'did you run git update-server-info on the server'

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone a github project on windows. I'm behind a firewall so can't use ssh. Running:

```
 git clone https://github.com/user/project.git
```

is returning `https://github.com/user/project.git not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?`

As it's not my project, is there a way to get around this?

EDIT:

The project I'm trying to clone is:

```
 https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2.git
```

EDIT:
   Sorry people - was a typeo. Git Bash on windows does't let you copy paste and i missed a letter.

Comment: Git bash has a way to copy and paste but it's not easy to figure out. Just right click the title bar (the one where the the 3 buttons including the x are) with the right mouse button. Then, in the menu, select edit followed by mark and you should know the rest....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One usual reason is the case (or, in this instance, according to the [OP directedbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167516/directedbit), a simple **typo**) .
GitHub repo url is case sensitive, as explained in "[Why are Github project document page urls case sensitive? What are the negative effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650488/why-are-github-project-document-page-urls-case-sensitive-what-are-the-negative/6650592#6650592)".

See as an illustration this [GitHub repo issue](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/issues/87):

> I had the same issue but the fix is insanely simple.
>   Lack of capitalisation for `KnpLabs` in the URLs so use the following instead.

```
[KnpMenu]
git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu.git

[KnpMenuBundle]
git=https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git
target=bundles/Knp/Bundle/MenuBundle
```

> => Update your urls from
>   `knplabs/KnpMenuBundle.git` to
>   `KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle.git` (case change)

Comment: Thanks - the URL from github is all case sensitive so I'm not sure if that is what is causing it. Edited the question.

Comment: Apologies. Re-did it an it was a type - Git Bash on windows wouldn't let me paste.

Comment: @directedbit no problem. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility