# GitHub pushing/pulling error

Tags: github

I'm kinda new to GitHub, and I just created my account and set it up, etc. I followed the steps very carefully on http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/ but then when I do the very last command ($ git push -u origin master) it says:

ERROR: Repository not found.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I have made the Repository, and it matches the name, but I still can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What output does `git remote -v` give?

Comment: git remote -v gives me: origin git@github.com:username/Helloworld.git (fetch)  origin git@github.com:username/Helloworld.git (push)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git will try to contact the remote repo you just declared in the previous line of the [GitHub tutorial](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/#_create_a_readme_for_your_repo):

```
  git remote add origin git@github.com:username/Hello-World.git
   git push -u origin master
```

As illustrated in:

- "[Why are Github project document page urls case sensitive? What are the negative effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6650592/6309)", and
- "[github http clone returns 'did you run git update-server-info on the server'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786013/github-http-clone-returns-did-you-run-git-update-server-info-on-the-server)",

your error message is likely the result of a:

- case mistake (`git remote add origin git@github.com:username/**h**ello-**w**orld.git`)
- or url error (`git remote add origin git@github.com:username/HelloWorld.git`, forgot the '`-`').

---

The [OP user1302394](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1302394/user1302394) confirms, in the comments:

> `git remote -v` gives me:

```
origin git@github.com:username/Helloworld.git (fetch) 
origin git@github.com:username/Helloworld.git (push)
```

Which means he/she combined a double whammy:

- case mistake (`world` instead of `World`)
- *and* url mistake (`Helloworld` insteadd of `Hello-World`)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I had made a mistake in the Repo name. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user1302394 ok. I have edited my answer to make your findings more visible.