# Git: Cloning through symlink requires password?

Tags: git, vim, github, add-on, git-clone

Using using vim's vundle package manager, I'm trying to clone the [ps1 plugin](https://github.com/PProvost/vim-ps1) to my machine.  I'm on a Windows 7 machine and my vimfile directory is symlinked so even though my git repository is located on *D:*, my git commands are using my *home* folder on *C:*.

My problem is that when I issue a clone command on my symlink'ed folder I am being prompted with for a github username and password.  Issuing the same command on my actual folder works as expected with no prompt.

From the windows command prompt I issue the git command

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pprovost/vim-ps1.git "D:\dev\git\.vim\bundle\vim-ps1"
```

and it works as expected, but if I try to execute the command 'through' the symlink

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pprovost/vim-ps1.git "C:\Users\ebeach\vimfiles\bundle\vim-ps1"
```

I am prompted for the github username and password.

My search for this answer is muddled with people trying to manipulate symlinks via github - I would just like to know why I am being prompted for a username and password in this particular case.

Thanks!

-- UPDATE --

This may be specific to the ps1 package since other packages seem to work without a problem.  As an example, the CtrlP github package clones without the prompt:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim.git "C:\Users\ebeach\vimfiles\bundle\ctrlp.vim"
```

But I still don't know why I am bring prompted for the ps1 package.

Comment: so what are the differences in your password setups between those repos? do you use credential-helper, .netrc or similar?

Comment: @eis I'm not a member of vim-ps1 or ctrlp and they are both public on github so I don't know why I am being prompted.  Probably unrelated:   I am a member of some projects on github so I do use git to connect to github in the same environment that I'm issuing these commands - but I do not use any credential helper.  I am prompted each time I push a change to github.

Comment: It seems to me that the authentication behaviour in github is inconsistent, as I sometimes get asked for credentials, sometimes not, when pushing and pulling from my repositories over https. I know that local credential caching is not an issue because it happens on clean machines.

Comment: Have you tried using WireShark or Fiddler to look at bits over the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand it, but it looks like I found an answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650488/why-are-github-project-document-page-urls-case-sensitive-what-are-the-negative/6650592#6650592).  It appears my problem was the ***case*** of the url, so where I had `https://github.com/pprovost/vim-ps1.git`, I should have respected the original case of `https://github.com/PProvost/vim-ps1.git`.

This solved my problem but I can't explain why one situation work and the other one didn't.