# How to resolve unable to push to GitHub due to "Invalid username or password"?

Tags: git, github

I have been having this issue for a short while. Basically, I was not able to push to a personal repo on GitHub from my work computer using GitBash with https.

Here's the error message

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/georgeliu1998/mlnd.git/'
```

Checked out these following threads but they don't seem to be the same situation.

- [git invalid username or password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29297154/git-invalid-username-or-password)
- [GitHub authentication failing
  over https, returning wrong email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913962/github-authentication-failing-over-https-returning-wrong-email-address)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that I need to log in using my username, but instead of using the normal GitHub account password, I should use a personal access token that can be created [here](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

### Edited content by Do Nhu Vy:

Because I am use GitHub feature named "Two-factor authentication" (It isn't a standard Git's feature, it's added feature by GitHub.com). After turn on the feature, I must create "Personal Access Tokens"

**Reference**

https://help.github.com/articles/about-two-factor-authentication/

https://github.com/settings/tokens

Comment: There's also https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication which says you can actually use an OTP but recommends using the token instead.