# Unable to Push to Github Tried Various Credentials

Tags: git, github, repository

I tried looking at this documentation:

[How to resolve unable to push to GitHub due to "Invalid username or password"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163501/how-to-resolve-unable-to-push-to-github-due-to-invalid-username-or-password?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[GitHub Error: Authentication Failed from the Command Line](https://medium.com/@ginnyfahs/github-error-authentication-failed-from-command-line-3a545bfd0ca8)

I am still having problems though.

Here is my situation:

1) I have enabled 2 factor authentication. In order to log into Github, I have to use a value sent to Windows Authenticator.

2) I have tried using this value.

3) I have also tried using the Personal Access Token created on github.

4) I have tried using my normal password.

None of these are working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong.

For some reason, I can't copy and paste my Personal Access Token, I manually have to type it in.

At least it works now.

**Edit:**

If I right click and then hit enter, it works, no more manually typing 9000 characters.