# git push not working from jenkins docker

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I am running a Jenkins docker image and trying to do a git push to through GitHub.
I did git commit in the PostSteps(Execute Shell) and PostBuild Actions with Git Publisher.
Is there some specific authentication I need to give in Jenkins?
I am not able to figure it out.
Thanks a lot in advance.

ERROR:

> Failed to push branch master to origin
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git push  HEAD:master -f" returned status code 128:
>   stdout: 
>   stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
>   fatal: Authentication failed for ''
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1903)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling Two Factor Authentication (2FA), you may see something like this when attempting to use `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push`:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': your_user_name
Password for 'https://your_user_name@github.com': 
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/your_user_name/repo_name.git/'
```

### Reason ?

From the [GitHub Help documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/#when-youll-be-asked-for-a-personal-access-token-as-a-password):

> After 2FA is enabled you will need to enter a personal access token instead of a 2FA code and your GitHub password.
>
> For example, when you access a repository using Git on the command line using commands like `git clone`, `git fetch`, `git pull` or `git push` with HTTPS URLs, you must provide your GitHub username and your personal access token when prompted for a username and password. The command line prompt won't specify that you should enter your personal access token when it asks for your password.

### Solution :

1. Generate a [Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). (Detailed guide on [Creating a personal access token for the command line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).)
2. Copy the Personal Access Token.
3. Re-attempt the command you were trying and use Personal Access Token in the place of your password.

Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21374369/101662