# Github pages ignores a directory

Tags: github, github-pages

Any idea why Github ignores this directory:

https://github.com/amahdy/DroneTrek/tree/master/ww

For example, this gives `404`

https://amahdy.github.io/DroneTrek/ww/WorldWind.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Github project document page urls case sensitive? What are the negative effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650488/why-are-github-project-document-page-urls-case-sensitive-what-are-the-negative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Github is case sensitive for file names.

try:
https://amahdy.github.io/DroneTrek/ww/worldwind.js

Comment: Didn't notice the problem in the `require` library: https://github.com/amahdy/DroneTrek/commit/5235f0a17b0a1be59fb3418f28e57db1a187a259